# How to get value of version when we click in the Sitecore client?

Tags: sitecore-client, versions

When I click in the Sitecore client to change versions, I would like to be able to run some code. So, is there any events trigger when I select any version number in the Sitecore client?

I am sharing screenshot from where I am selecting version. I need to get their value to be able to run some code.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add on @Chris Auer answer, you may find below the code snippet showing where you should perform the change.

You need to override the `OnLoad` method of the `GalleryVersionsForm` class from the namespace `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions` in the assembly `Sitecore.Client.dll`.

```
public class GalleryVersionsExtensionForm : GalleryVersionsForm
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)e, nameof(e));
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            //APPLY IMPLEMENTATION HERE
            //Code Snippet to retrieve selected version
            var formParameters = Context.ClientPage.Request.Form["__PARAMETERS"];

            var selectedVersion = formParameters.Split(',')[2].Replace(")", string.Empty).Split('=')[1];

            return;
        }
        Item currentItem = GalleryVersionsForm.GetCurrentItem();
        if (currentItem != null)
        {
            if (currentItem.IsFallback)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                htmlGenericControl.InnerText = Translate.Text("No version exists in the current language. You see a fallback version from '{0}' language.", (object)currentItem.OriginalLanguage);
                htmlGenericControl.Attributes["class"] = "versionNumSelected";
                Context.ClientPage.AddControl((System.Web.UI.Control)this.Versions, (System.Web.UI.Control)htmlGenericControl);
            }
            else
            {
                Item[] versions = currentItem.Versions.GetVersions();
                for (int index = versions.Length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
                {
                    Item obj = versions[index];
                    XmlControl control = ControlFactory.GetControl("Gallery.Versions.Option") as XmlControl;
                    Assert.IsNotNull((object)control, typeof(XmlControl), "Xml Control \"{0}\" not found", "Gallery.Versions.Option");
                    Context.ClientPage.AddControl((System.Web.UI.Control)this.Versions, (System.Web.UI.Control)control);
                    CultureInfo culture = Context.User.Profile.Culture;
                    string str1 = obj.Statistics.Updated == DateTime.MinValue ? Translate.Text("[Not set]") : DateUtil.FormatShortDateTime(DateUtil.ToServerTime(obj.Statistics.Updated), culture);
                    string str2 = obj.Statistics.UpdatedBy.Length == 0 ? "-" : obj.Statistics.UpdatedBy;
                    string str3 = obj.Version.ToString() + ".";
                    string str4 = obj.Version.Number != currentItem.Version.Number ? "<div class=\"versionNum\">" + str3 + "</div>" : "<div class=\"versionNumSelected\">" + str3 + "</div>";
                    control["Number"] = (object)str4;
                    control["Header"] = (object)Translate.Text("Modified <b>{0}</b> by <b>{1}</b>.", (object)str1, (object)str2);
                    control["Click"] = (object)string.Format("item:load(id={0},language={1},version={2})", (object)currentItem.ID, (object)currentItem.Language, (object)obj.Version.Number);
                }
            }
        }
        Item obj1 = Sitecore.Client.CoreDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Versions");
        if (obj1 == null || !obj1.HasChildren)
            return;
        string queryString = WebUtil.GetQueryString("id");
        this.Options.AddFromDataSource(obj1, queryString, new CommandContext(currentItem));
    }
}
```

It is in the IF STATEMENT of the IsEvent that you need to add your implementation. The statement is true when the user clicks on a version.

Note that you may also add your custom implementation, without overriding the whole class, after the base method call. Please see below.

```
public class GalleryVersionsExtensionForm : GalleryVersionsForm
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)e, nameof(e));
        
        base.OnLoad(e);
        
        if (Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            //APPLY IMPLEMENTATION HERE
            var formParameters = Context.ClientPage.Request.Form["__PARAMETERS"];

            var selectedVersion = formParameters.Split(',')[2].Replace(")", string.Empty).Split('=')[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have your code, you need to change the codebeside of the the `xml` for the version gallery UI.

**From**

```
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions.GalleryVersionsForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

**To**

```
<CodeBeside Type="YourNamespace,YourAssemblyName"/>
```

### IMPORTANT

When changing the version gallery UI, it will apply on both the ribbon and the on item version list. Please see screenshot below where the red squares highlight the affected sections

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

The above does not work on the Experience Editor. From a brief analysis, you will need to update/override the JavaScript file `SelectVersionGallery.js` to add your custom implementation to the event listener `selectversionoption:click`. The file can be found at the path `sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Galleries\Versions\SelectVersionGallery.js`

**UPDATE 2**

To retrieve the selected version, the only way is to read the `__PARAMETERS`. The returned value is

```
"item:load(id={110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9},language=en,version=1)"
```

So, you'll need to perform some replace and split in order to have the version number

```
var formParameters = Context.ClientPage.Request.Form["__PARAMETERS"];

var selectedVersion = formParameters.Split(',')[2].Replace(")", string.Empty).Split('=')[1];
```

**GetCurrentItem method implementation**

```
private static Item GetCurrentItem()
{
    string queryString1 = WebUtil.GetQueryString("db");
    string queryString2 = WebUtil.GetQueryString("id");
    Language index1 = Language.Parse(WebUtil.GetQueryString("la"));
    Sitecore.Data.Version index2 = Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(WebUtil.GetQueryString("vs"));
    Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(queryString1);
    Assert.IsNotNull((object)database, queryString1);
    return database.Items[queryString2, index1, index2];
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve this functionality through experience editor ?

Comment: Please see update section

Comment: How to get a clicked version details through this  code as you mentioned  "Item currentItem = GalleryVersionsForm.GetCurrentItem();" but it is throwing an error. I resolved this issue by creating method but i am not able to fetch clicked version details instead of previous version details.

Comment: Please see update 2 section. I have also updated the above code to where to use it and also the implementation of the `GetCurrentItem`

Comment: Okay ,@Hishaam Can we get version details through Experience editor with any event without javascript?

Comment: As far as I've seen, you'll need to retrieve it via JavaScript since the UI for the experience editor is on SPEAK compare to the content editor which is on XML

Comment: Okay @Hishaam , i am checking.

Comment: @Sonu have you been able to get the version?

Comment: Yes @Hishaam , I got the clicked version details through your code from Content editor.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can see if to override the code beside for `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Versions\Gallery Versions.xml`. It is currently set to `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions.GalleryVersionsForm`. This would allow you to insert some code as the next version gets loaded.